# All subgroup are Normal

Tags: group-theory

All subgroups of a abelian group are normal. But the converse is not true. If every subgroup of a group is normal, then what more can we say about the group?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $G$ is a finite non-abelian group where all subgroups are normal, then $$G \cong Q_8 \times A \times B$$ where $A$ is an elementary abelian 2-group (ie, all non-identity elements have order 2), $B$ is abelian of odd order and $Q_8$ is the quaternion group of order 8.
A proof can be found in for example Berkovich's Groups of Prime Power Order I believe.

Comment: Is something known about infinite groups?

Comment: Groups where all subgroups are normal are called Dedekind groups.  The finite case as explained above is proved in M. Hall, Theory of Groups.

Comment: What does "elementary" mean in the phrase "elementary abelian 2-group"?

Comment: An elementary abelian group is one where all elements (except the identity) have the same order. This order is then necessarily a prime.